# Charge distribution in a neutral conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

I have read and understood that if you give charge to a conductor, the charge comes on the surface of the conductor in electrostatic condition. But sometimes I get confused that whether the case is same with a neutral conductor? I mean whether in neutral conductor also, the free electrons come on the surface ?? If yes then there must be -ve charge induced on the surface and +ve charge inside the conductor ?? Please clarify how distribution occurs (if it does so in case of neutral conductors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an uncharged conductor al charges stay where the are, why should they move if there is no electric field i.e, force?